# HTTPS with NodeJS set request headers

Tags: node.js, https

Hey guys I'm struggling a little bit with Node JS and HTTPS requests. The following code actually works fine but I don't know how to set custom request headers like X-Forwarded-For and User Agent. Is there a way to add these?

Thanks :)

Here is my code:

```
    const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'offertoro.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET'
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {

  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`options`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) argument accepts a `headers` property.

```
const options = {
  hostname: 'offertoro.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
     'X-Forwarded-For': 'xxx',
     'User-Agent': 'Foo'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about `response` headers not request headers, because request headers are that are sent to you in a request body, you receive them not you set them
Rather you set `response` headers, which are you be sent when you respond with any action
If that's the case, you can set response header by

```
res.header('headersName','headersVALUE')
```